# vb net mysql reader progress

Tags: mysql, vb.net

hey guys, i wanna know if its possible to find out in a reader how much reading is left to do. My code will be below and i think it be fairly possible during a query that would be returning data but is it possible during a query designed to give data?

```
Public Function queryup(ByVal queryString As String, ByVal connection As MySqlConnection)
    Try
        Dim newQuery As String() = Split(queryString, ":")
        For Each Query In newQuery
            Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(Query, connection)
            Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            While reader.Read()
            End While
            reader.Close()
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        console("Error with MySQL: " & ex.Message)
        Return ex.Message
    End Try
    Return ""
End Function
```

that was the send data query, this is the receive data query.

```
Public Function querydown(ByVal queryString As String, ByVal connection As MySqlConnection)
    Dim returnInfo As New StringBuilder
    Try
        Dim newQuery As String() = Split(queryString, ":")
        For Each Query In newQuery
            Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(Query, connection)
            Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

            While reader.Read()
                For a = 0 To reader.FieldCount - 1
                    Dim strng As String = reader.GetString(a)
                    returnInfo.Append(strng & ",")
                Next

                returnInfo.Append(";")
            End While
            reader.Close()
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        console("Error with MySQL: " & ex.Message)
        Return ex.Message
    End Try
    Return returnInfo.ToString
End Function
enter code here
```

Comment: What's the difference between "returning data" and "giving data"? I can't see why you would call one SELECT query "sending" and another "receiving"

Comment: well there isnt much of a difference i guess, one of my functions is returning a large string and one isnt, i suppose theres no difference, the difference i was talking about was, i could do some work to make a progress thing because one has a fieldcount because data is actually being return, where as in the one thats just sending data i cant figure out how to track the progress of the reader.

Comment: Always try to explain with a _minimal_ example.

Comment: yeah i know im sorry, i know in my head whatim trying to ask, but i cant seem to explain it. basically when i call while reader.read() how do i tell how much reading its done vs how much is left? and i guess i need to clearify when i call reader.read thats when it sends my query string to the database correct?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, DataReader does not have a recordcount property, so your primary question of how much is left cannot be answered with the data reader. Can you use a data table and use its rows.count property instead?